# Cisco IOS rewrite http url

Tags: security, cisco, router, ios, cisco-asa

Is there a way that I can configure my router to rewrite http requests?

So for example, if:

```
http://www.example.com/porn.gif
```

is being accessed, it'll be re-written as:

```
http://172.16.0.1/denied.gif
```

But transparently returned to the client?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that Cisco IOS supports anything beyond basic interception and redirection of HTTP traffic.  Sounds like you want to use WCCP with your router and a separate Squid cache server in an Interception Proxy configuration.

http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/InterceptionProxy#WCCP_-_Web_Cache_Coordination_Protocol

Comment: How can I do an HTTP redirection?  That would work for our needs as well.  Thanks!

Comment: See the document I linked above.  There are plenty of examples and pointers to Cisco documentation.